# transparency groups in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

The Asymptote file

```
size(5cm);
draw(unitcircle ^^ expi(-3pi/4) -- expi(pi/4), red + linewidth(1cm) + opacity(0.5));
settings.outformat="pdf";
```

produces this

[image]

which is clearly not what was intended.  I'd like to be able to draw (fill, etc.) several paths (or perhaps even an entire `picture`) that draw over each other as though they were opaque, but such that things drawn before the entire group are still visible (as in transparency).  In TikZ, I can do this using `transparency groups` (although that feature has minor issues if you combine it with enough other esoteric features; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82004/484)).

How can this be done using Asymptote?

Comment: Can the foreground–background blending options as given [here](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Pens.html) help?