# How can I move a single node in a tikz plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, plot

I can't find an answer online, please help me. The following plot shows the percentage of 3 groups. The red line is the average (and needs to stay at 13.8).

How can I move ONLY the node "2.9" a little bit up? (here it is not really problematic, but I have other graphs where the number and the red line are overlapping - looks terrible!)....

Thank you very very much!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=28mm,right=28mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    line width=0.5pt,
    bar width=7pt,
    tick style={line width=0.4pt}}}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Test,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ylabel=percentage,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3},
    xtick=data,
    width=12cm,
    bar width=10pt];

\addplot [black, fill=black,nodes near coords]
coordinates {(1, 55.6) (2,18) (3,2.9)};

\addplot[red,mark=none, sharp plot, line width=0.6pt]
coordinates {(1,13.8) (3,13.8)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a true MWE... there are certainly some packages not needed for this problem. And try to avoid an empty line between each line of code.

Comment: @Jake: Ok, sorry, I was distracted ;-) I remove my previous comment

Comment: @Kate, people will be more likely to answer if a true MWE is posted. As Christian notes, you have many packages/options that only serve to complicate the issue. Here's a potential MWE (linebreaks lost in comment, but you get the idea): `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,xtick=data];
  \addplot[nodes near coords] coordinates {(1, 10) (2, 5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` With this MWE, you could ask a more general question: How to adjust the position of the label node on a single bar?

Answer (score 6):

You can move a single `node near coord` by using a conditional `yshift` that checks the current coordinate index, which is stored in the macro `\coordindex`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    line width=0.5pt,
    bar width=7pt,
    tick style={line width=0.4pt}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Test,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ylabel=percentage,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ybar,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3},
    xtick=data,
    width=12cm,
    bar width=10pt];

\addplot [black, fill=black,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        yshift={\ifnum\coordindex=1 1ex\else 0pt\fi}
    }
]
coordinates {(1, 55.6) (2,11) (3,2.9)};

\addplot[red,mark=none, sharp plot, line width=0.6pt]
coordinates {(1,13.8) (3,13.8)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question properly then your problem is that the average plot sometimes overlaps the values on top of the bars. I have came up with a solution, but you will have to omit the `nodes near coords` option from your bar plot, and manually add the nodes after drawing the average plot.

[image]

The solution I'm posting has different values than yours to demonstrate the two options I have included. See the two middle bars, first I have added 1.5 ex height to the node, the second I have added a faded background so the crossing red line won't be so disturbing. (Note that if you use the faded background solution you'll have to include the `fadings` TikZ library.)

Also I have lengthened the average plot line to extend to the edge of the bars.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=28mm, right=28mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}

\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, fadings}
% fading from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82004/8844
\tikzfading[name=fade out,
    inner color=transparent!0,
    outer color=transparent!100]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={%
    font=\footnotesize,%
    line width=0.5pt,%
    bar width=7pt,%
    tick style={line width=0.4pt}}}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        xlabel=Test,%
        ymin=0,%
        ymax=100,%
        ylabel=percentage,%
        enlarge x limits=0.15,%
        enlarge y limits={value=0.05,upper},%
        ybar,%
        symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4},%
        xtick=data,%
        width=12cm,%
        bar width=10pt];%

        \addplot [black,%
            fill=black] coordinates {%
                (1, 75) (2, 50) (3, 50) (4, 35)
            };

        \addplot[red,%
            mark=none,%
            sharp plot,%
            line width=0.6pt] coordinates {
                (1, 52.5) (4, 52.5)
            };
        % omit the following two lines if you dont want the average plot
        % lines extended to the edge of the bars
        \draw[red, line width=0.6pt] (axis cs:1, 52.5) -- ++(-0.5 * \pgfplotbarwidth, 0);
        \draw[red, line width=0.6pt] (axis cs:4, 52.5) -- ++(0.5 * \pgfplotbarwidth, 0);

        % add values to the bars manually
        \node[above] at (axis cs:1, 75) {75};
        \node[above=1.5ex] at (axis cs:2, 50) {50};
        \node[above,
            fill=white,%
            path fading=fade out,%
            text opacity=1.0,%
            inner xsep=2em] at (axis cs:3, 50) {50};
        \node[above] at (axis cs:4, 35) {35};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution -- simply draw the the 3rd ybar independently and add `node near coords` key with `raisebox` command into the option.

Note: To avoid shift of xticks, `ybar` key should move to individual addplot.

```
nodes near coords=\raisebox{0.3cm}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[pdftex,11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=28mm,right=28mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    line width=0.5pt,
    bar width=7pt,
    tick style={line width=0.4pt}}}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=Test,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    ylabel=percentage,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    %ybar,
    symbolic x coords={1,2,3},
    xtick=data, 
    extra x ticks={3},
    width=12cm,
    bar width=10pt];

\addplot [black, ybar, fill=black,nodes near coords]  % <--- remove (3,2.9)
coordinates {(1,55.6) (2,18)};

\addplot [black, ybar, fill=black,nodes near coords=\raisebox{0.3cm}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}]      
coordinates {(3,2.9)};                          % <--- to here and then raise the label where 0.3cm can be changed.

\addplot[red,mark=none, sharp plot, line width=0.6pt]
coordinates {(1,13.8) (3,13.8)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```