# Misplaced nodes near coords in stacked ybar plot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I have this stacked ybar plot and having trouble to proper align the nodes near the coords. It works fine on all bar but the one with offset `65`. I already tried `\ifnum` as @Jake suggested here: [How can I move a single node in a tikz plot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188756/how-can-i-move-a-single-node-in-a-tikz-plot) 
This works, but throws me this error twice:

```
Extra \else. \end{axis}
```

When I add the `\ifnum` to my main document, I get even more of them. 
Any suggestions how to fix this, or  why the label is missplaced in the first place?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{migration.tsv}
index   Kategorie   data    offset
5   five    1573    6
6   six 270 7
7   seven   497 65
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     \pgfplotstableread{migration.tsv}\migrationtable 
     \pgfplotsset{%
             width=\textwidth,
             height=.4\textheight,
             every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize}, %
             every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize}, %
             compat=1.13%
                 }%
      \begin{axis}[%
          ybar stacked,
          scale only axis,
          x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east}, 
          xtick=data,
          every node near coord/.append style={%
              anchor=south}
              ]
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!50!white] table[x=index,y=data] from \migrationtable;
      \addplot[draw=black,fill=red,nodes near coords] table[x=index,y=offset] from \migrationtable;
      \legend{values,offset}
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the `\ifnum` block I used:

```
 every node near coord/.append style={%
       yshift={%
         \ifnum\coordindex=2 2ex\else 0pt\fi
       }%
 }
```

Also tried `\newcommand{\equals}{=}` to wrap the `=` as @egreg pointed out in question that can't find anymore.

I guess this is somehow similar to [Center nodes near coords in a stacked ybar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36114/center-nodes-near-coords-in-a-stacked-ybar-plot?rq=1) but I couldn't figure out how  to use this to solve my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove this style option `every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south}`, and replace it with the following options:

```
nodes near coords align={anchor=south},
nodes near coords bar offset=1
```

Now, even if you increase the offset in your table by random amounts, the nodes will always appear nicely on top, without the need for you to manually shift them.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{filecontents*}{migration.tsv}
index   Kategorie   data    offset
5   five    1573    6
6   six 270 7
7   seven   497 65
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{migration.tsv}\migrationtable 
\pgfplotsset{%
    width=\textwidth,
    height=.4\textheight,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize}, %
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\footnotesize}, %
    compat=1.13%
}%
\begin{axis}[%
    ybar stacked,
    scale only axis,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east}, 
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords align={anchor=south},
    nodes near coords bar offset=1
]
\addplot[draw=black,fill=blue!50!white] table[x=index,y=data] from \migrationtable;
\addplot[draw=black,fill=red,nodes near coords] table[x=index,y=offset] from \migrationtable;
\legend{values,offset}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```